# docker container can only access by host when the docker0 in promiscuous mode

Tags: docker, centos7, promiscuous-mode

As the title. I can only access my docker container from the host when docker0 in promiscuous mode,
even I had stopped my firewalld.service.

I start the container by this command
`docker run -p 9000:80 --name nginx --rm nginx`.
And when I try to connect to the server:
`curl 127.0.0.1:9000`, it returns: **Recv failure: Connection reset by peer**

But if I run tcpdump on the docker0 like this:
`sudo tcpdump -i docker0`
everything just works as expected. [After some searching,](https://serverfault.com/questions/516123/packets-only-get-forwarded-when-tcpdump-running-on-bridge) I found the tcpdump command convert the docker0 interface to promiscuous mode.

my host system: centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64
Docker version: 19.03.8

Comment: How are you starting the container?  How are you trying to access it?  Have you made changes to the default Docker network setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze I had edited my question for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find a solution! It turns out to be a bad interface. I have to remove the docker0 interface and restart the docker service. Then the problem just disappears!

```
sudo ip link delete docker0
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```